# Laravel: How to generate seeders in a custom directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm using Laravel 5.5 with [laravel-modules](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v2/introduction) v2.

It's easy to generate **migrations** in a custom directory (inside a module, specifically):

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --path=Modules/User/Database/Migrations
```

But seems that this isn't possible with **seeding** classes:

```
php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder --path=Modules/User/Database/
```

> The "--path" option does not exist.

or passing full relative path:

```
php artisan make:seeder Modules/User/Database/Migrations/UsersTableSeeder
```

> Creates this exactly folder structure inside **./database/seeds/**

or passing full absolute path:

```
php artisan make:seeder /Modules/User/Database/Migrations/UsersTableSeeder
```

> file_put_contents(\my\file\system\project\database/seeds/C:/Program Files/Git
>     /Modules/User/Database/Seeders/UsersTableSeeder.php): failed to open str
>     eam: No such file or directory

How to generate seeders with artisan command in a custom directory?

Comment: Use this package. It generates seed files for your database https://github.com/ACFBentveld/ASeeder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The `GeneratorCommand` (which the Seeder extends) doesn't care about whether or not folders exist, because it's just going to write the file only.

```
/**
 * Get the destination class path.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return string
 */
protected function getPath($name)
{
    return $this->laravel->databasePath().'/seeds/'.$name.'.php';
}
```

The only way to achieve what you want is to write your own `Seeder` command and allow for directory traversal. You can inspect the `Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateMakeCommand` to see how it's done, it's not very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can't but you can do it with your custom code after do following steps:

> 1. Copy file from Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeederMakeCommand.php to your
>      folder.
> 2. Modify getPath() function.
> 3. Bind this class to container to override core.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems bcs in our team we want to create two folder, one for real data seeders and the other for fake data seeders.

 in DatabaseSeeder file you can define your classes from another path ( namespace ) and it will work after running php artisan db:seed command

in my case I define new call  :

```html
            $this->call([
                //real data classes from \database\seeds path
            ]);

            $this->call([
                //fake data from database\seeds\tests path
                'Database\Seeds\Tests\AuthControllerTestSeeder'
            ]);
```

do not forget to define your namespace (Database\Seeds\Tests\AuthControllerTestSeeder) in

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a special directory when creating a seeder you just need to modify this section
vendor/laravel/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeederMakeCommand.php

protected function getPath($name)
{
$name = str_replace('\', '/', Str::replaceFirst($this->rootNamespace(), '', $name));

```
    if (is_dir($this->laravel->databasePath().'/seed')) {
        return $this->laravel->databasePath().'/benih/'.$name.'.php';
    }

    return $this->laravel->databasePath().'/seeds/'.$name.'.php';
}
```

change the part "return $this->laravel->databasePath().'/seeders/'.$name.'.php';"
to "return [Your directory]'.$name.'.php'.
and don't forget to delete the
database/seeds directory in your project

or if you want the "seeders" you created to go to the database/seeders directory you just need to delete the database/seeds directory.
after that when you type the php command artisan make:seeder YourSeeder
will go to the database/seeders directory