# How to run seeder under Users module

Tags: laravel

I need to run Laravel 6 application
and after running migrations I see that many tables are empty, including users.

In modules subdirectory I found files

- /Modules/Users/Database/migrations/create_users_table.php

  /Modules/Users/Database/seeders/UsersSeeder.php

Last file has default users

It was strange that running command

```
php artisan module:list
```

I see list of modules, but not Users module, as I expected

So I got error running in the root of my app:

```
php artisan module:seed Users
RuntimeException  : Module [Users] does not exists.
```

I tried to run only this seeder, but again with error :

```
$ php artisan db:seed --class=/Modules/Users/Database/seeders/UsersSeeder

   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [/Modules/Users/Database/seeders/UsersSeeder] does not exist.
```

How can I run seeder under Users module(which I do not see in output of php artisan module:list)
?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `composer dump-autoload` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use artisan command to make seeder

```
php artisan make:seeder UsersSeeder
```

You get the file in

> database/seeds/UsersSeeder

Then you can call

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UsersSeeder
```

Instead of

```
php artisan db:seed --class=/Modules/Users/Database/seeders/UsersSeeder
```

Do not forget to run

> composer dump-autoload

after first command

Comment: Sure, I have run composer dump-autoload
I do not habe to create a new seeder, but I need to run existing seeder in the module
/Modules/Users/Database/seeders/UsersSeeder
and I can not run it

Comment: In that case this might help you can use it for running your seeder too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232669/laravel-how-to-generate-seeders-in-a-custom-directory